# Download PDF from URL not ending on pdf generating corrupted PDF file

Tags: scala

I am downloading PDF files from URLs using scala using below code and it is working fine

```
var out: OutputStream = null;
var in: InputStream = null;
val url = new URL( """http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf""")
val connection = url.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
in = connection.getInputStream
val localfile = "sample2.pdf"
out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localfile))
val byteArray = Stream.continually(in.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
out.write(byteArray)
```

but when I give URLs which does not end with "PDF" for example URL given below

```
https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=51&ved=0ahUKEwjq19ah8MbKAhXEj44KHeWAB6g4MhAWCBgwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.us.fulbrightonline.org%2Fuploads%2Ffiles%2Fapplication_samples%2FForm9B_ETA_Reference_Form-Sample.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGZnon3ygHDJnW12Te8JrBR-o6jyw&sig2=OgSgD4HnUXZ9l_VS0AwGFg&bvm=bv.112454388,d.c2E&cad=rja
```

it does not generate PDF file properly. While opening that PDF "Not a PDF or corrupted error" comes.

Answer (score 1):

If you read your URL and chop off the hash at the end (all that comes after `.pdf`, you'll see the link that Google is pointing to embedded in there:

```
https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=51&ved=0ahUKEwjq19ah8MbKAhXEj44KHeWAB6g4MhAWCBgwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.us.fulbrightonline.org%2Fuploads%2Ffiles%2Fapplication_samples%2FForm9B_ETA_Reference_Form-Sample.pdf
```

Here's the direct link (use this for your project):

```
http://www.us.fulbrightonline.org/uploads/files/application_samples/Form9B_ETA_Reference_Form-Sample.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, but i've to read URLs from excel files given by client and URLs can be in the form not ending with "pdf".